# ASP.NET MVC - Adding multiple model items to a single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

For my MVC project, I want to add Model elements to a table in the following format:

```
╦═══════════╦
║ Season #  ║  <-------(SeasonID Selector DDL)
╩═══════════╩
╔═══╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║   ║ Team Name ║      Player Names       ║
╠═══╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ GSW       ║ PlayerA PlayerB PlayerC ║
║   ║           ║ PlayerD Player E        ║
║ 2 ║ OKC       ║ PlayerA PlayerB PlayerC ║
║   ║           ║ PlayerD Player E        ║
║ 3 ║ CLE       ║ PlayerA PlayerB PlayerC ║
║   ║           ║ PlayerD Player E        ║
║ 4 ║ SAS       ║ PlayerA PlayerB PlayerC ║
║ 5 ║ TOR       ║ PlayerA PlayerB PlayerC ║
╚═══╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

I managed to do this by adding the `SeasonTeam`  into a `Viewbag list` and looping through each one `Team` name in the `Season`. I would then loop through each item in the `Roster` Model and compare it with the `SeasonTeamID` in the `Viewbag list`, so if `Viewbag list.seasonTeamID == model.SeasonTeamID`, then add player name to row. I think the following code can help explain.

Relationship between entities: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e9Fb.png)

Roster Model:

```
public partial class Roster
{
    public int RosterID { get; set; }
    public int SeasonTeamID { get; set; }
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public virtual SeasonTeam SeasonTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Index:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("seasonID", (SelectList)ViewBag.SeasonList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    </p>
}
<table class="table"> 
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SeasonTeamID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SeasonTeam.Team.TeamName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Player List")
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@{ 
    int rowCount = 0;
    var team = (List<SeasonTeam>)ViewBag.teamList;
}
@foreach (var t in team)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@(rowCount += 1)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.SeasonTeamID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.Team.TeamName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @* Loop through each player in roster *@
            @{ var modelList = Model.ToList();}
            <div class="row">
                @for (int i = 0; i < modelList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (modelList[i].SeasonTeamID == t.SeasonTeamID)
                    {
                        if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
                        {
                            @:</div><div class="row"> 
                            <div class="col-md-3">@modelList[i].Player.LastName</div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="col-md-3">@modelList[i].Player.LastName</div>
                        }                        
                    }                    
                }
            </div>
            @*End loop*@
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = t.SeasonTeamID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = t.SeasonTeamID })
        </td>       
    </tr>
}
```

Roster Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? seasonID)
    {
        var rosters = db.Rosters.Include(r => r.SeasonTeam).Where(r => r.SeasonTeam.SeasonID == seasonID).OrderBy(t => t.SeasonTeam.Team.TeamName);



        var sList = db.Seasons.OrderByDescending(a => a.SeasonID).ToList()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                SeasonID = s.SeasonID,
                Desc = "Season " + s.SeasonID
            });
        ViewBag.SeasonList = new SelectList(sList, "SeasonID", "Desc", seasonID);

        var steam = db.SeasonTeams.Include(r => r.Team).Where(r => r.SeasonID == seasonID).OrderBy(r => r.Team.TeamName);
        ViewBag.teamList = steam.ToList();

        return View(rosters.ToList());
    }
```

The problem is that I do not want to go through the each and every player in the `model` (and compare its `SeasonTeamID` with the team list's `SeasonTeamID`) whenever I iterate through a team name, especially when there will be around 100+ people playing per season. Is there an alternative approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An initial recommendation, is to change this:

```
var modelList = Model.ToList();
```

for this:

```
var modelList = Model.Where(x => x.SeasonTeamID == t.SeasonTeamID).ToList();
```

Therefore, modelList now will only have the players you are interested in, so you won't have to iterate every single one of them, and you will be able to eliminate this 'if':

```
if (modelList[i].SeasonTeamID == t.SeasonTeamID)
```

Comment: Wow it's such a simple solution. Thanks! I'm fairly new to this (worked on this project for around 2 months) and I thought I can only do `.Where(x => x.SeasonTeamID == t.SeasonTeamID)` in the controller.